# How can I import a class from back4app, which contains images, into another back4app database?

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

I have a back4app parse database that has a class containing images. I need to import this class into another back4app parse database. When I export it to json and attempt to import it, I get the following: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. Followed by an error stating access denied. What do I need to do to get this to work?

To clarify the solution: the files must be cloned into the new database, which can only be done by contacting back4app directly and asking them to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you sent a email or talk at chat with Back4App, the error that you reported is necessary clone your files/images.